# JavaScript If Count

Tags: javascript, function, timer

I think I must be missing something very obvious. Using this code I want to count up and trigger a background change on a timer; however it doesn't pass the variable, each time the timer calls the function it is passing a undefined variable.

**Worth noting:**

- Looked at the consol - no errors
- I know Jquery would arguably be better but the site can't have jquery due to some nasty legacy issues (thats a whole other question)

**The Code**

```
<script>
/* Get the body element */
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
/* Call the function */
changebackground();
/* Set the starting count */
var changecount = 1;
/* Change function */
function changebackground(changecount) {
    if(changecount=1){
        body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(/templates/images/background_1.jpg)';
        changecount = 2;
    }
    else if (changecount=2) {
        body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(/templates/images/background_2.jpg)';
        changecount = 3;
    }   
    else {
        body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(/templates/images/background_3.jpg)'; 
        changecount = 1;
    }
setInterval(function(changecount){changebackground();},3000);
}
</script>
```

Comment: your if statements need to be `==` not `=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `changecount` as a parameter to changebackground(). You have it as a global variable so no need to list it in the parameter list.

```
function changebackground() {
    ...
}
```

Then change your setInterval call to:

```
setInterval(changebackground, 3000);
```

And also move the call outside of changebackground(). You only need to call setInverval() once, not every time changebackground() is invoked.

Finally, use `==` for comparisons, not `=`.

```
if (changecount == 1) {
    body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(/templates/images/background_1.jpg)';
    changecount = 2;
}
else if (changecount == 2) {
    body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(/templates/images/background_2.jpg)';
    changecount = 3;
}   
else {
    body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(/templates/images/background_3.jpg)'; 
    changecount = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

few things are wrong.

the comparison operators where incorrect. You Also don't need to pass in the variable to the `changebackground()` function as the variable is global.

This should work.

```
/* Get the body element */
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
/* Call the function */
changebackground();
/* Set the starting count */
var changecount = 1;
/* Change function */
function changebackground() {
    if (changecount == 1) {
        body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(/templates/images/background_1.jpg)';
        changecount = 2;
    } else if (changecount == 2) {
        body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(/templates/images/background_2.jpg)';
        changecount = 3;
    } else {
        body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(/templates/images/background_3.jpg)';
        changecount = 1;
    }
    // line just added for debugging
    alert(changecount);
    setInterval(changebackground(), 3000);
}
```

[Working Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pvrME/)

Comment: Why is it that the function is being triggered all the time. Notice how the alerts just keep coming?

Comment: @tim.baker because of the last line `setInterval(changebackground(), 3000);` the alerts are there just to show its working.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the argument between the brackets of the function: `changebackground(changecount)`

(also when you first call the function)

Answer (score 0):

You've set `changecount` as a global variable. setInterval will not pass changecount into the function.

Try this:

```
setInterval(function(){
    changebackground(changecount);
},3000);
```

You've also incorrectly reassigned variables in your if blocks. Use the comparison operator instead:

```
if(changecount == 1){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` to call a function from inside that function repeatedly:

```
function changebackground(changecount) {
.
.
.
setTimeout("changebackground("+changecount+")",3000); // change to this
}
```

Also use `==` for checking instead of `=` like:

```
if(changecount==1){ ...  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing changecount to your anonymous function, but instead you have defined it as a parameter. Use the following code instead:

```
<script>
/* Get the body element */
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
/* Call the function */
changebackground();
/* Set the starting count */
var changecount = 1;
/* Change function */
function changebackground() {
    if(changecount=1){
        body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(/templates/images/background_1.jpg)';
        changecount = 2;
    }
    else if (changecount=2) {
        body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(/templates/images/background_2.jpg)';
        changecount = 3;
    }   
    else {
        body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(/templates/images/background_3.jpg)'; 
        changecount = 1;
    }
    setInterval(changebackground,3000);
}
</script>
```

This executes your function every 3s. You don't have to pass the variable as your it is global anyway.